# How do i pass variable dice FROM diceNumber(),DiceScript TO diceno IN Box_Collider Script

Tags: unity

[image: This the Box_Collider Script][image: This the dice script.]

Want to pass dice variable to 10 same script(Box_Collider). If i generate random no in Box_collider then ten random numbers are generated.

Comment: Are these two scripts on the same game object or on different objects?

Comment: Different objects

Comment: When i generarte random number on Box_Collider Script , Numbers are generated 10 times as Box_Collider Script is on 10 Object.

Comment: You are really hard to understand. Do you want the DiceScript to generate one number which is the same for all the Box_Collider's until the player changes it by pressing space? Or do you want each Box_Collider to have a different number unique to that object?

Comment: DiceScript to generate one number which is the same for all the Box_Collider's until the player changes it by pressing space. It works when i write it like this int diceno = 5; instead of writing 5 i want a random number there.

Comment: We have features like copy-pasting text. Why do bother to put up code _screenshots_? Could you please copy-paste your code instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one instance of `DiceScript` in your scene, then you can declare the variable `dice` as static. (`public static int dice;`). This does two things. First, all instances of DiceScript share the value of that variable. But if you have only one instance then that makes no difference. Second, you can refer to that variable in any other script as `DiceScript.dice` without requiring a reference to an object of type DiceScript.

Like this:

```
if (value == DiceScript.dice) {
    // do something
}
```

But this solution won't work if you ever want to have more than one instance of DiceScript in your scene. In that case you would make the variable non-static and give the Box_Collider a `public DiceScript controllingDiceScript` variable. You would then use the inspector to assign objects with DiceScript to the objects with Box_Collider which are supposed to be controlled by it. You can then use `if (value == controllingDiceScript.dice)` to check the value of the specific DiceScript you assigned to this specific Box_Collider.